# Fetching specific node fields instead of whole nodes using EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, nodes, database

The standard for fetching specific nodes from the database in Drupal 7 goes something like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', 'page');
$query->fieldCondition('field_category', 'value', $category_id);

$result = $query->execute();
$nids = array_keys($result['node']);
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

For better performance, is there any way to specify that I want to load only certain fields (the title for example) of the nodes instead of loading all their their fields?

I prefer a solution that doesn't use SQL to benefit from all the goodies Drupal functions offer (reliability, caching results, future proofed, ...).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. EFQ can only return the entity id's.

While there might be ways around it, there is a logical reason for that: Modules might alter the values of those fields in various hooks, there is no guarantee that the directly returned values are the same as when loading an entity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what do you recommend I use if I, let's say, want to fetch the titles for 500 nodes? what's the most efficient way of doing so? Thanks again!